# Mailchimp API success indicator

Tags: c#, postman, mailchimp

When I run a Mailchimp POST API to delete a member ("/actions/delete-permanent"), I can see the correct result in the MailChimp UI (member is gone), however the return response (in the variable "responseString" below) is blank  ("").  I'm using C#:

```
                    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)requestDeleteMember.GetResponse();
                    Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    responseString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    streamReader.Close();
```

Mailchimp documentation for this action does not explain the response, and Mailchimp support advised "consult an expert".

EDITS:
Deleted comments about Postman returning a "1".  Looking more carefully I see that Postman returns "204 No Content", which matches my C# code.  So, I'm assuming that "no content" is the correct answer for a "successful" response.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck using the [MailChimp.Net SDK](https://github.com/brandonseydel/MailChimp.Net), which as `MailChimpManager.Members.DeleteAsync` [method](https://github.com/brandonseydel/MailChimp.Net/blob/master/MailChimp.Net/Logic/MemberLogic.cs#L184). Not sure on whether the response body is meaningful in this case.

Comment: Thanks, good lead. The Mailchimp "Playground" can be useful too. I edited my comment; I believe I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

See Edits.  On closer review, Postman returns the same result as my C# code. So, I've got the best response data I'm going to get from the Mailchimp API:  "no error, no response message".